# Limiting the number of boxes per line of display

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code which is basically a box with small input boxes inside.
I want to have maximum of 4 input boxes on the same line, and to break line if there are more. The reason i don't do this manually is because a .js file will add input boxes to the code eventually.

```css
.formPanel {
    display:flex;
}

.formOption {
    width: 25%
}

.formBox {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="formBody">
            <div id="insertForm" class="formPanel">
                <div class="formOption">
                    <h4>Task 1</h4>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Task1" class="formBox">
                </div>
                <div class="formOption">
                    <h4>Task 2</h4>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Task2" class="formBox">
                </div>
                <div class="formOption">
                    <h4>Task 3</h4>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Task3" class="formBox">
                </div>
                <div class="formOption">
                    <h4>Task 4</h4>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Task4" class="formBox">
                </div>
                <div class="formOption">
                    <h4>Task 5</h4>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Task5" class="formBox">
                </div>
                <div class="formOption">
                    <h4>Task 6</h4>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Task6" class="formBox">
                </div>
            </div>
```

What's the css option to make this happen? I already put the width of each box to be at 25%, but i have display:flex on the parent so they end up all on the same line.

In this fiddle there is the example i'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/wr41ah63/7/
Every task is on the same line but i want to have one line with 4 tasks maximum.

Comment: Use `flex-wrap: wrap;` on your `.formPanel` to allow the container to wrap content to the next line if it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `flex-wrap: wrap` along with `display: flex` to `.formPanel` to make it work. Otherwise, no matter what width you set, it will always display on single line.